# Negation of <script> tags in querySelectorAll not working

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, screen-scraping, innertext

I am trying to get the user-readable text from the html of a website by selecting the body element, excluding the  tags, and then on top of it printing the innerText of the elements which is supposed to ignore the  tags:

```
doc.querySelectorAll("* > body:not(script)")
[].forEach.call(matches, function(elem) {
   console.log(elem['innerText'])
}
```

However, I still see the content of the script tags together with the visible text in the body of the html document.

I am doing this in the background script of my chrome extension, by obtaining the DOM of this website through the XMLHttpRequest() API: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07VTK654B/ref=ods_gw_bfw_H1_D_XPL2_mn_en?pf_rd_r=88S22KRX4KSFBBJAPXJM&pf_rd_p=c98ea2f1-9fa3-4bbb-9122-c5620c491f4f](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VTK654B)

Comment: I think you should put a space between body and not, actually you are selecting the "non-script body tag" (`"* > body :not(script)`)

Comment: It still gives the content inside <script> tags

Comment: I think there is something in your dom so... Are you using something like `cheerio` or similar? All the three methods in this page seems to exclude the script tag in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szv8wnod/). I can think only to nested script tags, like `<div><script>...</script></div>`, in that case maybe you should have some trouble with these methods

Comment: I am using XMLHttpRequest() to send an HTTP request to that amazon website and, as a response, obtaining its DOM. I was thinking maybe innerText and :not only exclude the immediate children <script> tags of the body but not the nested ones; however I tried nesting some in that JSFiddle and those three methods still work.

Comment: I checked out on your page, the problem is indeed some nested `<script/>`, so if you catch a `<div/>` with a script inside it, if you ask for the `innerText` you will get also the js part. I think you should take a recursive approach

Comment: Oh that's really helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all direct children of the body that are not script elements, the selector should be:

```
document.querySelectorAll("body > :not(script)")
```

Comment: For some reason it still gives me the content inside scripts like functions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not going to display your HTML content, you could remove all the script tags and then get the body `innerText`:

```js
doc.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(s => s.remove());

let yourFinalText = doc.querySelector('body').innerText.trim();
```

Unluckly, these kind of misbehaviours seems to appear especially in Chrome, because Firefox standards are different: the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) states that `innerText` should capture just printable/visible text, while `textContent` should capture  also the non visible content. This seems not to apply on Chrome environments, I don't know why so.